# Prove that $\sqrt n$ is irrational unless $n = m^2$ for some natural number $m$ (from Spivak Calculus 3.ed., §2, Ex 17b).

Tags: prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

I've looked up the solution to this problem in the Spivak Caluclus Answers Book and found the following proof:

If $\sqrt n = a/b$, then $nb^2 = a^2$, so the factorization into primes of $nb^2$ and of
$a^2$ must be the same. Now every prime appears an even number of times in the
factorization of $a^2$, and of $b^2$, so the same must be true of the factorization of $n$. **This implies that $n$ is a square**.

I agree with all the steps up to the last one. Why is it that if some number $n$ can be factorized in a such a way that the composition would include even number of the same prime, then $n$ must be a square of some other number?

What if I take say 18. It can be represented as 3*3*2, it has an even number of primes in it and at the same time is not a square of some other number $m$.

Comment: You're missing that an even number of primes doesn't mean an even number of distinct primes. Here $18$ is made up of three primes: $2,3$ and $3$ again.

Comment: The statement in the header is false.  Take $n=2$.  I think you were trying for the statement "The square root of a natural number is either a natural number itself or it is irrational".

Comment: @lulu I've just quoted the way it appers in Spivak's book. There is a long passage providing some details before it though.

Comment: That may be, but it is wrong.  As I say, consider $n=2$. Then $n$ is rational (obviously) but it is not equal to $m^2$ for any natural number $m$ (also obviously).  I think you (and possibly Spivak) meant the statement I wrote.  That is, I think you meant $\sqrt n$ not $n$ and you meant to add that $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I've just noticed what you meant! It was meant to be $\sqrt n$ (corrected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is said that *every prime appears an even number of times in the factorization of $n$*, this is counting each prime **with multiplicity**.

In your example $18 = 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2$, $3$ is listed twice. So at the end, the number of primes counted with multiplicity in the factorization of $18$ is odd.